# Django template ifequal - request GET and object id

Tags: django, templates

Why is this not the same??

```
{% ifequal gender.id request.GET.gender %} {{gender.name}} {% endifequal %}
```

gender.id = 1
request.GET.gender = 1

Please help, I think it's simple :)

Comment: What does your view code look like?  Are you sure you're passing in everything correctly?  Try adding `Gender ID: {{ gender.id }}; Request Gender: {{ request.GET.gender }}; Gender Name: {{ gender.name }}` into your template to see what you see.  If everything's working correctly you should see `Gender ID: 1; Request Gender: 1; Gender Name: Male(or at least something)`

Comment: `request.GET.gender` is probably a `string` while `gender.id` is `integer`.

Comment: This is the whole template code

{% if request.GET.gender %} {% for gender in search_filters.genders %} {% ifequal gender.id request.GET.gender %} {{gender.name}} {% endifequal %} {% endfor %} {% else %} - choose - {% endif %}

AND

When i write to the template - request.GET.gender = 1   and  loop in search_filters.genders gender is 1, 2, 3   and  gender.name = 'test', 'test2', 'test3'

I dont know is this is the best way to do it, i'm a newbee..

Comment: Try like this:  `{% ifequal gender.id|slugify request.GET.gender %}`

Comment: //rebus - Still dosent work, but i think your right, how can i convert both stings in ints and them compare ?

Comment: I'd recommend to get the value of `request.GET.gender` in some variable in your view, turn it into a integer with `int()` and then put it in context with some meaningful name such as `selected_gender_id` or something.

To check they types of data you are using try something like `print type(search_filters.genders[0].id), type(request.GET.get("gender"))` in your view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using django > 1.0 you might try

```
{% ifequal gender.id|stringformat:"s" request.GET.gender %}....{% endifequal %}
```

Or using d to have an decimal integer

```
{% ifequal gender.id request.GET.gender|stringformat:"d" %}....{% endifequal %}
```

Reference:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#stringformat

Comment: Hey, I use django 1.0

I have tried  gender.id|stringformat:"s"   with no luck :( ..

Comment: When i print request.GET.id|stringformat:"d" to the template, it's empty, and it still not work :(

Comment: Do you have 'django.core.context_processors.request' in TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS inside your settings.py? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request

Comment: Yep, request.GET.gender is 1  in the template... So i dont get i why i can't compare the to values :(

Comment: I already had tried that - {% ifequal gender.id request.GET.gender|stringformat:"d" %} {{gender.name}} {% endifequal %}

I won't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay!, I updated my Django version from - 1.0.2  to  1.2.1

WOOP

Now it worked ;)

```
gender.id|stringformat:"s"
```

Thank you all for the advice ;)